# How do I get rid of a Bluebird warning when chaining more than one flatMap operator in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, rxjs

This code gives me this error

`Warning: a promise was created in a handler but none were returned from it`

```
var Observable = Rx.Observable;

var source = Observable.range(0, 3);

source
  .flatMap(item => {
    console.log('getting first promise');
    return Observable.fromPromise(
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(5)
      })
    );
  })
  .flatMap(item => {
    console.log('item ==', item);
    console.log('getting second promise');
    return Observable.fromPromise(
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(4)
      })
    );

  })
  .subscribe(x => console.log('sub1 == ', x));
```

If I remove the second `flatMap` operator, I don't get the error. Why is the the second RxJS flatMap operator causing a Bluebird warning, but the first flatMap isn't? And, of course, what do I need to fix in how I'm using Bluebird Promises?

Here's a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hBY2ss2aSgdahDAtLJTb?p=preview) that demonstrates the issue, you'll see the warnings in Chrome's Developer Console

Comment: This is RxJS dropping the ball, nothing you an really do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't tell but that message is from bluebird, not from Rxjs. You can have a look here : https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/854. It seems to be your exact same issue which is dealt with there.

Comment: Correct, this is a Bluebird error. Sorry if I didn't make that clear enough in the original post. I just figured Bluebird may be incorrectly inferring that I'm not returning a Promise somewhere because of the unique environment of RxJS, which is why I incorporated it into the post.

Answer (score 1):

While this is annoying (I don't remember anything in the Promise spec that says you have to return null or your computer will yell at you), I can PR a fix to Rx in the next day or two.